# Is 8gb enough to support Ubuntu MATE without storage issues?

Tags: ubuntu, memory, storage

After becoming familiar with Rasbian and Terminal, I decided to try something new with ubuntu MATE. Aside from the microSD card that the Raspberry pi came with, which I want to keep the Rasbian operating system loaded on, I have an 8 gig microSD card at my disposal. I wrote the image to the card, and I have it up and running with no issues.

Here's where the trouble starts. I have used my pi for a few days, and I have started getting low memory warnings. I only have around 400 megabytes of free storage left. I have tried resizing the file system and removing unneeded packages, but my question doesn't concern the means of making free space.

---

***Is eight gigabytes enough to support ubuntu MATE?***

***Do I need more? 16? 32? 64?***

Comment: Have you tried to run `ncdu /` and checked what the disk hogs were?

Comment: Have you resized the filesystem?

Comment: This actually varies a lot with the version of Ubuntu MATE. I used an 8GB card for a long time, then had to go bigger for 16.04.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how much space Ubuntu mate needs specifically, but the Raspberry Pi maxes out at 32 GB, and that's the size I use on all but one of my Pi's and I never have space problems. Amazon usually has 32 GB sd cards for about 17 bucks. 8 GB cards are just about useless, imho.

The Ubuntu mate website says:
You’ll need a microSD card which is 4GB or greater to fit the image. The file system can be resized to occupy the unallocated space of the microSD card, similar to Raspbian.

Answer (score 1):

Should work on `8GB`. But there will be storage issues in time, as only about `700MB` will be unused on clean system.

Please note, that if you are buying a card for RPI, buy a good one (class 10). On low-end cards, it works like a crap.

Answer (score 0):

8 GB will be  perfectly fine and will leave you with about 3 GB of space left on the card after install.